# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ToDoItem"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to the Xcode Tutorial on a iOS ToDoApp. I've done all the steps and certainly I've got compile errors.

I've searched around and I've seen that I'm not the only one with this problem, and I have tried peoples solutions but with no success.
This is my error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ToDoItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ToDoListTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing `ToDoItem.m` (or better said the `@implementation ToDoItem`) in your project. Either it's not there at all or the file is not included in the build target.

Try to search `@implementation ToDoItem` in your project. If it's missing, you have to add it. If it's not missing, make sure that the file is added to the target you are trying to build.